# Adding a Substring to a String without knowing the position

Tags: python, java, arrays, string, parsing

I want to add a char(newline) to a String by specifiying the location with a Substring.

Is that possible in Python or Java?

Here's how I imagine it,

Newline is added to the String at the position between two arrays `'],'`:

```
str = [[a,b,c], [d,e,f]]

result = addString(str, '],', '\n')
print(result)

Output:

[[a,b,c],
[d,e,f]]
```

Comment: You can find where in the string the first array ends and the second begins, and insert at that position. In particular for Java, look at the documentation for the indexOf() method in the String class.

Comment: I want to use this method on a list of Strings with differing lengths, so I can't use indexOf()

Comment: What do you mean you can't? It's perfectly possible to iterate through a list and do what you need to do with each individual string it contains. And if one or more of those individual strings contain textual representations of more than two arrays, you can use `split()`. In any case, if there are circumstances that prevent you taking a certain approach to solve the problem, you should state that in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python-wise, your `str` variable uses a reserved keyword and missing the quotes.

you can do it in python as below:

```
mystr = "[[a,b,c], [d,e,f]]"       
print(mystr.replace('],', '],\n'))
```

prints:

```
[[a,b,c],
 [d,e,f]]
```

Comment: Thanks, to achieve the desired effect like described in the question, we can alter the code a little: 
`print(mystr.replace('], ', '],\n'))`